# Image in toolbar: layout:height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

In a basic activity, I am trying to put an image attached to the tool bar. In this code in the ImageView section `android:layout_height="217dp"`. I don't want to give it this way, as I recently read that for the algorithm to work for all devices. So my ultimate choice was to use: `match_parent` or `wrap_content`. If I use `217dp` my app will look different. However if I use `match_parent` or `wrap_content` for the image view, I am getting a huge tool bar, which takes almost half of the screen. What should I do?

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="@color/colorWagner">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="217dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/wagner"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_first"
        android:layout_height= "wrap_content" />
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide an image of how you want the toolbar?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf - I added an image. Dont mind the DOT ...it is in the image itself.

Comment: I agree with @RahulAgrawal, you can reduce the size of your image, and apply `"wrap_content"`, or you can try using percentage as I do in the answer I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the size of the image. You will need to reduce the size of the image via some tools. I have had similar issue in past. Try setting a fixed height for the image before you save the image in android. It should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use the following code in your .java file

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try using percentage:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/wagner"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />


<Space
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

You can vary the numbers in `layout_weight`, to adjust the percentage. In this case the percentage will be 50% for each element which are your button, and an empty space.